# Laplacians on Kaehler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I have a question about Laplacians on Kaehler manifolds. In a paper I am reading it is obtained that

\begin{align}
\overline{\partial}i(\frac{1}{2}g^{ik}f_{\overline{k}}\partial_{j})\omega = \frac{1}{2}f_{\overline{k}\overline{j}}d\overline{z}^{j}\wedge i(\partial_{k})\omega,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
i(\frac{1}{2}g^{j\overline{k}}f_{\overline{k}}\partial_{j})\overline{\partial}\omega = \frac{1}{2}f_{\overline{k}}(\overline{\partial}i(\partial_{k}) + i(\partial_{k})\overline{\partial})\omega
\end{align}.
I have a difficulty to understand these calculations, for example where is $g^{ik}$ in the final expression. Besides, I can not find some basic reference where Laplacians on Kaehler manifolds are calculated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: The paper is:Kaehler manifoldswith real holomorphic vector fields by O. Munteanu and J. Wang